# How to tell apt to use the latest package by default?

Tags: debian, apt

I put jessie-backports in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but it seems that apt will not automatically use the packages from backports but older packages.

However, if I use `apt-cache show` to check the version it shows the latest, and I am able to use `apt install xxx=<latest-version>` to install it.

How to tell apt always use the latest package by default?

Comment: See this post and its mention of "pinning": http://askubuntu.com/questions/27362/how-to-only-install-updates-from-a-specific-repository

Comment: Before doing this, it's worth wondering why we specifically set the backports repositories up so that they *don't* get picked by default...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @cutrightjm has mentioned `apt-pinning` is the solution.

If you create a file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/backports` with the following content

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stretch-backports
Pin-Priority: 800
```

`apt` will always install packages from `stretch-backports`, except when you pin another package source with a priority higher than 800.

If you want to see all available versions of a package, their priority and which one will be installed, you can use `apt-cache policy <packagename>`.

Comment: One more question: when I have multiple versions of one package from  multiple sources, how do I tell apt to use the latest version? The preference doesn't seem to be able to do that.

Comment: It's really not recommended to mix many package sources. Debian is intended as a distribution which prefers stability over stability. So if you add another package source, you should only pin the packages you want to install to a higher Priority.